# Integrating payment to Delphi Android application

Tags: android, delphi, paypal, paytm, instamojo

I'm developing an Android application using Delphi 10.1 and I need to integrate payment gateway (instamojo/paytm/paypal). I could not find any examples for integrating payment gateway to Delphi Android application and after the successful payment, I need to update the values in Server. Please provide some example.